# secure connection between three parties: android client and facebook and spring server

Tags: android, spring

I have an android client and a server written using spring framework. The thing is that the client doesn't use a system username/password to login in but it is loging on using facebook api login and when i got a token i am sending it per http to the spring server. the spring server should also connect with this token to facebook and make sure the token sent by android client is valid. I am using RESTful to communicate between android and the server written in spring. My question is that how can i encrypt connection between android client and spring server so that nobody will be able to read the facebook token sent. after searching online i found out that i should use https and contact a certificate company to issue secure certification ! anybody knows easier solution.

Comment: You should use https :-)

Comment: To get a free ssl certificate try let's enrypt

Comment: i think spring provide certificate by default for android. this article make Aauth without using certificate !
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-android/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/auth.html